# Authentication Token x-www-form-urlencoded body to a JSON body

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I can get an authentication token using Microsoft Graph API on Postman using the Post Token api call.
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{AzuretenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7B%7BAzuretenantID%7D%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

However, I need to make the call in a program we have that only accepts a JSON body. I currently use a x-www-form-urlencoded body as represented in the image below.

[image: x-www-form-urlencoded]

I tried to write it as a JSON body in the "raw" body section of Postman.

```
{"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id":"7721b276-c186-42e0-b81c-c8cf0bfc5f21",
"client_secret":"Lu48Q~5SQ8ge6O2OXvsfYJJH-ga0DdHCNsgubaea",
"scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"}
```

However I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: c5e88698-3b60-4763-85ea-b807ec280000\r\nCorrelation ID: 0998db90-1b32-48e1-b095-7ceb3fe2ff2f\r\nTimestamp: 2023-05-01 18:37:24Z",
    "error_codes": [
        900144
    ],
    "timestamp": "2023-05-01 18:37:24Z",
    "trace_id": "c5e88698-3b60-4763-85ea-b807ec280000",
    "correlation_id": "0998db90-1b32-48e1-b095-7ceb3fe2ff2f",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft identity platform `/token` endpoint follows standard [document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) and accepts only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` message format.

So `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is mandatory and sending JSON request bodies will result in an error.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way around this?